# How to create a truly in memory jacrabbit repository

Tags: repository, jackrabbit, jcr

I've been trying to figure out if it is possible to have a jackrabbit repository to be run completely in memory.

Whatever I try in order to run the repository fully in memory, I still end up with a repository directory full of files on my disk?

If anyone has figured this out I'd much appreciate if you could explain how to achieve it.

Thanks

Piersyp

Comment: Have you got a SearchIndex configured? That writes the indexes to file.

Answer (score 1):

See this 4+ year old blog post, which hopefully still applies and is helpful: http://modeshape.wordpress.com/2008/02/22/speedy-unit-testing-with-jackrabbit/

Comment: Thanks Randall, but I've been over that one and however I try to configure my repo, I still end up writing to disk. When I started with jackrabbit and the JCR about a week ago I thought obviously here would be a way to run quick tests in memory, now I'm beginning to feel that there is not. Even the test harness provided by jackrabbit employing a "TransientRepository" writes 6+ MB and 287 files to disk! I think I'm starting to understand why people don't trust adobe any more!! :(